# php function as variable

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working with a wordpress plugin. This plugin has a function `tribe_events_week_get_the_date()` that print date like **`2016-05-31`**

I want to customize the date. So I use this code

```
<?php 
    $cDate = tribe_events_week_get_the_date();
    $cToday = new DateTime($cDate);
    echo $cToday->format(' D '); 
    echo $cToday->format('n . j'); 
?>
```

When this code print, the $cDate value also print automatically. I mean `tribe_events_week_get_the_date()` still print its value.

I want only the echo value.

Any idea how to use this function?

Comment: you will have to modify the tribe_events_week_get_the_date() function to return the value instead of echo-ing from inside the function

Comment: @Liquidchrome thank you :) While I editing the function I got a boolen parameter inside it. $echo =true/false so its handle value printing.